# mobile radio tower is off

Tags: imei, network-signal

typing `*#*#4636#*#*` on my mi max3 xiaomi will take me to my phone setting and I after turning mobile radio tower ON it urns back to OFF again after a few moments.
I am not able to place any calls as it tells me AIRPLANE MODE is on and it is not ON. I have factory reset the phone already and have the latest MIUI 11.0.2 installed. Things are the same even when I flash the Chinese ROM or other custom ROMS.

any tips how to remedy this ?

[image]